# return false but continue in the same scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class='google' href="www.google.com>google</a>
```

says I can't change the above markup but I want to disable the hyperlink, I do this

```
$('.google').click(function(){
    return false;
    windows.open('www.gmail.com');
});
```

I expect after return false my code will work but it doesn't, why?

Answer (score 10):

Because [after return statement, rest of the code will never be invoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). That is the default behavior of every programming language.  You can prevent the redirection by using `event.preventDefault()`. For that, use like this

```
$('.google').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('www.gmail.com');
});
```

For `event.preventDefault()` vs `return false` see [event-preventdefault-vs-return-false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: I bet you mean `window`, not Windows.